# javascript aggregation disables the font-your-face module and views-slideshow on the main page

Tags: javascript, caching, theming

When I turn on the aggregate js option on my drupal commerce (kickstart 1) site, the font-your-face (dealt with by FYF module) and the slideshow on the main page stop working. The fonts seem to show up fine on the other pages.
Does anyone has any idea why it might be so? 
I obtain a "syntax error" in the JS console.

Comment: Please provide us with errors from your JS console. I just tried it on http://kasgard.pl/ and font your Face works flawlessly, so it's not a bug in core or this module.

Comment: woops @Mołot thanks for this suggestion it turned out that the problem was related to the _field slideshow_ module and libraries. I had to replace to use the 2.1.1 version of the imagesuploaded library, as per https://drupal.org/comment/7874537#comment-7874537

Comment: Feel free to post that as a self-answer then :) also, the very error message from the JS console could help future users to Google this question, so don't be shy to edit it into a question.

Comment: dzięki wielkie ;-)

Answer (score 1):

It turned out the problem is with the *fields slideshow* module and its use of js/jquery libraries.
I've realised that JS error happens  after calling some slideshow libraries, so i googled for aggregate js / field slideshow.
As per https://drupal.org/comment/7874537#comment-7874537 , I used the 2.1.x version of the imagesloaded library and everything worked nice afterwards.